# One word for repeated acts of sick behavior?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an essay on the gentle treatment of pedophiles by the criminal justice system. What is one word for their 'acts' or their 'misdeeds' that is harsh and not so light and easy? For example:

'...provides an environment for them to commit their ----'

I tried https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dirty%20deed

I would really prefer a single word.

Thanks for your time and help.

sixie6e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[depravity](https://lexico.com/en/definition/depravity), with the plural **depravities**:

> moral corruption; wickedness.

Your sentence would be:

> '...provides an environment for them to commit their **depravities**.

Comment: I agree "indulge" is better than "commit", but I believe "indulge their depravities" would be better than "indulge _in_ their depravities". Their depravities are an urge that they _are_ indulging, not an activity _in which_ they're indulging. But this is a minor point; what you have is already clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

'...provides an environment for them to commit their attrocities'

'...provides an environment for them to commit their offenses'

'...provides an environment for them to commit their brutality'

'...provides an environment for them to commit their savagery'

'...provides an environment for them to commit their barbarity'

Comment: I'll address the downvoter's concern if they voice it.